# How to fix a partially uprooted tree? Please help

Tags: trees, tree-care

A few days back due to strong winds a peepal tree(i.e. Ficus religiosa or sacred fig) was partially uprooted near my house. It is approximately at a 45° angle. It is 7-8 meters tall. Almost half the roots are out of the surface. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Trees are remarkably tough, there have been cases where trees have been partially uprooted and then grown well once stood back up. I would try to stand it back up and stake it well to support it whilst the roots grow and support the tree back in place.

Answer (score 3):

When we travel in hurricane-prone regions such as the low lying islands of the Bahamas it is a fairly common sight to see fruit-laden trees supported by sturdy forked sticks at a precarious angle and surviving quite well. The problem is that when the roots are pulled from the ground they are subjected to the drying winds and desiccate rapidly making it difficult for them to re-establish themselves if reintroduced to the ground. And even if they do form new roots, the tree is weakened on that side making it vulnerable to the next prevailing wind from that direction.

Massive root loss often triggers a distress crop of fruit; the weight of the fruit only contributes to the difficulty, pulling the tree even further over on the leaning side. So for fruiting crops there is a vested interest in keeping that tree going just to get the crop while you work on a replacement tree. But a replacement may take a while to obtain either by home grown or purchase, and may take some time to achieve the size of the existing, which is why a supply of heavy forked sticks and big dimension lumber comes in handy.

The fruit of the F. religiosa is not significant as food, so we can set that aside for a moment. However in some countries this Ficus is regarded as a religious symbol - there may be local sensitivities with respect to keeping specimens in good order. No doubt it will be easy for you to gauge from discussions with neighbours whether this is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to advice based on my own experience.

I had a large plum fruit tree (even higher than your tree, 8-10 m high) that was uprooted one winter almost identically to your tree - 45 degrees. I should say I live in a really windy area. The tree even stayed that way for several months. With the help of a friend and some ropes we just "returned" the tree to its original position. No special care afterwards.

The tree continued living as if nothing happen. :)

I would just perhaps advice fixing the tree to the neighboring tree for a season or two, just in case. In my case, it wasn't needed.